# Error While Integrating iAd Adapter in Admob Mediation SDk

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, iad

I am trying to integrate iAds in Admob mediation SDK for that purpose, I downloaded `iAdListAdapter` from [Mediation website Download Link](https://dl.google.com/dl/googleadmobadssdk/libadapteriad.zip) and added it into my xcode project but now when I try to compile the project it is giving following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape", referenced from:
  -[GADMAdapterIAd getBannerWithSize:] in libAdapterIAd.a(GADMAdapterIAd.o)
  -[GADMAdapterIAd adjustADBannerToAdSize] in libAdapterIAd.a(GADMAdapterIAd.o)
"_ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait", referenced from:
  -[GADMAdapterIAd getBannerWithSize:] in libAdapterIAd.a(GADMAdapterIAd.o)
  -[GADMAdapterIAd adjustADBannerToAdSize] in libAdapterIAd.a(GADMAdapterIAd.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADBannerView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libAdapterIAd.a(GADMAdapterIAd.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADInterstitialAd", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libAdapterIAd.a(GADMAdapterIAd.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please guide what am I doing wrong or what is the correct way of adding iAds to Mediation SDk by the way: I am using XCode 4.6 with min sdk 5.0

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turned out that i needed to add **iAd.Framework** and remove **-all_load** Flag in the project, which solved the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

For People who use auto linking please include "#import < iAd/iAd.h >" in any of your source files/